# How can I eliminate the extra space added to the bottom when the value dips below 0 on the Y axis in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts

I styled my chart with a legend below it like this, and you'll see a grey chart faintly rendered on another chart behind it for comparison (their data scales are different, couldnt put them both on the same actual chart):

[image]

As you can see, because the data on the front chart dipped below zero on the Y axis, 0 on the Y axis was moved upward way further than it needed to (the bottom of the chart normally lines up with the bottom of the gray chart behind it). I can of course resize and move the gray chart so that it's Y0 and the front chart's Y0 align, but that still leaves a big gap between the lowest data on the chart and the legend.

How can I eliminate this extra space below the lowest data rendered on the chart? I want the lowest value rendered to touch the bottom on the chart.

Putting my code, I think, wouldn't be useful here, since this behavior seems to be universal across Chart.js, and what I'm looking for is probably a setting in the options object that I don't know of yet, or know of, but don't know it can produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Found the setting for it:

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    autoSkip: true,
    maxTicksLimit: 0,
    stepSize: 0.1
  }
}]
```